# cant select values using html u a tags but works for ahref

Tags: html, css

```css
u[JSON Fetch Request example]
{
    text-underline-offset: 3px;
}
```

```html
    <h1><u>JSON Fetch Request example</u></h1>
```

in above code ,I am unable to offset the underline.
but I can choose the a tag as my following code works as per mdn article(ps:i am unable to find mdn article):

```css
a[href="https://cnn.com/"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://cnn.com/">cnn</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a CSS class to the element. You can also select  elements with `.querySelector`.

```css
.r{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a <u>test</u> of the selection of u elements w JavaScript.</p>

<p>This is a <u class=r>test</u> of the selection of u elements w/o JavaScript.</p>
```

Comment: i wanna use html and css only

Comment: Still, a JavaScript example of how to style an element based on its text content might be helpful here.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how it's done w only HTML/CSS by adding a class to the `<u>` element.